# Creating 16-bit .COM executables files using gcc

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, mingw, object-files

Is there a way to create 16-bit `.COM executables` (DOS) using some gcc distribution for windows (for example MINGW)?

Comment: Don't people normally do this with TurboC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use http://www.openwatcom.org as Compiler. The Watcom compiler can create *.com files. Instruction are on this pdf http://www.openwatcom.org/ftp/manuals/current/tools.pdf